# Entity Framework one column return value from another column

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am using Entity Framework code-first. I have this column already in my table:

```
public Int64? Discount { get; set; }
```

Now I am creating this column as a computed column:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public Int64? computedDiscount { get; set; }
```

I have used `Discount` column in many codes of my project, is it possible to force `Discount` to return `computedDiscount` value instead of replace `Discount` to `computedDiscount` in all of my source code?

Comment: Try to use the DataMember attribute as decorator of the Discount property: `[DataMember(Name = "computedDiscount")]`.

Comment: @Vyrira : It does not work and return Discount  value yet.